# Coinbase OAuth. Increase default send limits

Tags: oauth, coinbase-api

I have OAuth application in coinbase. After creating the app in the settings, I see :

> **wallet:transactions:send** is limited $1.00/day per user

The [documentation](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/coinbase-connect/permissions) says that I can increase these limits in the application settings. but there is no such option in the settings, these values are read-only.

If I set a limit in the redirect url that I want (more than $1.00), I get the error:

> Send limit is over allowed limit ($1.00).

How can I increase these limits?

Comment: Just want to check whether anyone here found an answer for this

Comment: I too saw this issue when developing an app. I believe it it might be a failure on their side. Typically what should happen is that the amount should default to the meta data amount you provide. Instead, you can set it to $1 for now. When a user clicks the link, it will ask them to change the amount themselves before authorizing.